# Get top 10 most used words in text fields

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have an index containing thousands of documents, each one of them having a full text field.

I want to search through all those fields and fetch the 10 most common words that come back most often.

I would also like a way of visualizing it on Kibana if that's possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common way to achieve that is to duplicate your full text field with a `keyword datatype`. That will get you able to make `terms aggregation` on that field - [doc here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html). Maybe you could consider to do a `significant term aggregation` - [doc here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-aggregations-bucket-significantterms-aggregation.html), thus to avoid the presence of stopwords and common words. In ES 6.x you could use also the `significant text aggregation` - [doc here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-aggregations-bucket-significanttext-aggregation.html), without create the `keyword` field, but i never try it, i don't know how it works. Instead if you need to retrieve the frequency of the words for each document, you should use the `termvector` - [doc here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/docs-termvectors.html)