# Get the most frequent terms of text field

Tags: elasticsearch

How do I get a list of all individual tokens of a text field along with their document frequency. I want this to build a domain specific list of frequent (and therefore useless) stop words.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49792349/get-top-10-most-used-words-in-text-fields) covers all the methods I found so far but

- "keyword" data type is not an option because im interested in individual terms (so tokenisation is necessary)
- "significant term aggregation" is not an option because im interested in the most frequent, not the most significant terms
- "termvector" is not an option because I need it for the hole index not just a particular document or a small subset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to enable field_data on your field to do this.
But be careful it can impact a lot the heap memory used.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. Especially fielddata_frequency_filter looks promising. Nevertheless using field data and agg feels like quite a overhead for such a "simple" thing. I'm wondering how solr handles this differently (sol has a "terms" request handler for exactly that kind of questions)